# How to plot a histogram using Matplotlib in Python using 2 lists?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am reading a file which has data in the form of:

```
1 2
3 2
4 4
```

Each line has two integers 1st is x and 2nd is y.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X, Y = [], []
for line in open('data_simple.txt', 'r'):
   values = [float(s) for s in line.split()]
   X.append(values[0])
   Y.append(values[1])


n, bins, patches = plt.hist(X, Y, normed=1, facecolor='g', alpha=0.75)

plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Num of Cores')

plt.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: ´bins´ must increase monotonically, when an array
```

Comment: what would a histogram of two lists look like? Do you want to produce a two-dimensional histogram?

Comment: Yes, two-dimensional histogram.

Comment: Where you able to find a solution for the error? I would like to do the same.

Answer (score -1):

A 2D histogram is created with 
[plt.hist2d](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html)

```
n, xbins, ybins, image = plt.hist2d(X, Y, normed=1)
```

Answer (score -2):

`matplotlib` `hist` accepts the data as the first argument, so it should be:

```
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(Y, X, normed=1, facecolor='g', alpha=0.75)
```

Or if that is not what you want, use `bar` instead.

Why is this being downvoted? I just corrected a false statement of the question, while the question itself was so unclear that it is not possible to give an answer which is solving the problem. Fairness and good manners are not everyone's strength.

Comment: If you do not understand the question, don't answer it. The code shown in this answer does not help in any way to solve the problem, hence the answer is not useful, => reason to downvote. Note that a downvote on an answer which is not useful is indeed fair and of good manner, because it allows future readers to directly see that there is a problem with this answer and prevents them from blindly using it.

Comment: I understood the question. But if the OP forgets to mention that he wants a 2D-histogram, then I can't know that. I'm not a mindreader. Thus I stated that `plt.hist` takes the data in the first argument and the bins in the second argument, which is the most common error using `hist` and usually solves the problem. So considering the information given at the time when I posted my answer, it was indeed helpful.

Comment: There is also no indication in the question that the first column of the data should be the `bins`, so this answer will lead to the same problem as before. Answering a question which is unclear always comes with the risk to misunderstand it. But noone forces you to answer such questions anyways.

Comment: Of course there is an indication that the first column of the data should be the `bins`. `bins`, usually on the x-axis, are frequently named `X`, why `Y` is usually the data. And using `hist` usually means that a histogram is wanted and not a 2d-histogram. Asking an unclear question always comes with the risk that someone cannot mindread. But noone forces you to punish someone with a downvote who still tried to be nice and help.

Comment: Omg. I hope you do not feel punished by a downvote. A vote is on a question or answer, not on you personally. It does btw. not make sense to do revenge downvoting - that is grotesque and not how votes are to be used. It is furthermore a bit strange that now that you do realize the OP wants a 2D histogram you still try to argue about it.

Comment: No, I don't feel punished personally. I just feel that it might lower the motivation to post answers if a try to help gets downvoted. Revenge-downvoting? Well, I didn't do that. And btw... I was not the one who started arguing. The only thing I did was to ask why I received a downvote. I didn't even *correct* my answer using 2d-hist, since I accepted that you answered it. But just look who wrote the first comment under my answer and started arguing. ;)

Comment: My first comment answers the question you asked (which should have been a comment already).